# My wordpress site goes blank when I edit wp-config

Tags: php, wordpress, directory

I'm trying to edit my `wp-config` file so my wordpress information is hidden on my site. When I edit it, the entire site goes blank. When I go to the wordpress dashboard I get the following error message:

> ERROR:The themes directory is either empty or doesn’t exist. Please check your installation

All I've added (just before the last line [something about require_once]) is:

```
define('WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME', 'media');
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', ABSPATH . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME );
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://brightpixelstudios.com/'.WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME); 
define('WP_PLUGIN_DIR', WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/plugins' );
define('WP_PLUGIN_URL', WP_CONTENT_URL.'/plugins');
```

Any ideas what might be causing the problem? It could be worth mentioning that I have both a `.com` and a `.co.uk` name for the same site.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be useful for you to post more code, more importantly the mention of your `require_once`. FYI: I'm not a pro at Wordpress.

Comment: Would it be secure to post the entire php code list up? I'd happily do that if it made answering easier.

Comment: I don't know Will. Like I said, I'm no Wordpress pro. Did you add `require_once` yourself, or was that already part of the original code from the install?

Comment: The require_once was already there - cheers for trying to help anyway Fred :)

Comment: Ok. I found a few links which may help. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/blind-site-after-editing-wp-config-file - http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-admin-blank-page - http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-admin-goes-blank-after-saving-changes-theme-issue - *sorry I couldn't be of more help*. Cheers

Comment: You might want to try asking WP-specific questions on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ instead of here.

Answer (score 0):

hi its look like this causing please remove this line 
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://brightpixelstudios.com/'.WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME);

or please provide me the full wp-config so i can check what causing issue

Answer (score 0):

```
define('WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME', 'media');   
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', ABSPATH . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME );    
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://brightpixelstudios.com/'.WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME);          
define('WP_PLUGIN_DIR', WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/plugins' );         
define('WP_PLUGIN_URL', WP_CONTENT_URL.'/plugins');
```

It is better to use / after media like

```
define('WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME', 'media');      
to     
define('WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME', 'media/');
```

this some time creates problem when WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME is used in your files it gives problem.

Example :

```
With '/'
WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME.'/'.UR_FOLDER_OR_FILES_ETC // This is right way.

Without '/'
WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME . UR_FOLDER_OR_FILES_ETC // This can create problem.
```

If still this dont work, then provide ur config file.

Comment: Thank you for your help Manoj :) When I try this the site loads very slowly and the pictures don't appear. Any idea what this could be?

Comment: whitehead i think there is no reason that upper part will make site slow, can u paste here your config file? so that i can figure out !

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark here, but I've seen this happen when the editor changes the permissions of the wp-config.php file upon saving such that the user for the webserver process cannot read it.